# Difference between Android SensorManager and Google Fit raw sensor data?

Tags: android, android-sensors, google-fit, heartrate, samsung-health

For my app I need to read the user's latest heart rate to send in every message.

One is the Android SensorManager and the other is Google Fit's Sensors. Also there is Samsung's Health app (don't think this one will give me the data I need as I don't need past data unless I just query it for the latest heart rate).

What is the difference between these methods of accessing the user's heart rate?
Is one better than the other for my purposes? Or are they all the same?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#STRING_TYPE_HEART_RATE

https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors